# Create folders with variables in the path (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, mkdir

I want to create folders like this with variables in the path, I tried join-path and it tells me that "System.Object[]" cannot be converted to type "System.String" required by parameter "ChildPath". The specified method is not supported.

```
$variables\A\$variables
$variables\I
$variables\L\Cs\cz
$variables\L\Da\dk
$variables\L\Nl\nl
$variables\L\En\uk
$variables\L\En\us
$variables\M
$variables\U\Ed
```

I'm just new to powershell and this is my script:

```
$variables = Read-Host -Prompt 'Type here'
$dir = Join-Path -path $PSScriptRoot\$variables -ChildPath "A","I","L","M","U" 
#-AdditionalChildPath I don't know how to properly create more childpaths，they are created at the wrong path
mkdir $dir
```

edit：

Considering that the L folder has many subfolders, so I tried foreach nested, which created the folders correctly, but at the same time returned a lot of `An item with the specified name...already exists.`

```
$var = Read-Host -Prompt 'Type here'
$loc = "Cs\cz","Da\dk","Nl\nl","En\uk","En\us"
$dir = foreach ($childPath in "A\$var","I","L","M","U\Ed") {
    Join-Path $PSScriptRoot\$var $childPath
    foreach ($additionalChildPath in $loc) {
        Join-Path $PSScriptRoot\$var\L $additionalChildPath    
    }
}
mkdir $dir
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-ChildPath` parameter accepts only a single string, so you have to call `Join-Path` multiple times, if you'd like to *individually* join multiple child paths to a base path, creating an *array* of paths (if that is what you want):

```sh
$dir = foreach( $childPath in "A","I","L","M","U" ) {
    Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot\$variables -ChildPath $childPath
}
```

This captures all (*implicit*) output from the `foreach` loop body in variable `$dir`, automatically creating an array like this:

```text
c:\foo\A
c:\foo\I
c:\foo\L
c:\foo\M
c:\foo\U
```

Alternatively you may take advantage of the fact that the `-ChildPath` parameter accepts pipeline input (as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7.2#parameters)):

```sh
$dir = "A","I","L","M","U" | Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot\$variables -ChildPath { $_ }
```

The `-ChildPath` argument is a [*delay-bind* script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) that simply passes the current pipeline object to the `Join-Path` command. As in the `foreach` loop, `Join-Path` gets called for each of the letters that are passed as input to the pipeline. Again, all output is captured in `$dir` as an array.

---

In a comment you mention `-AdditionalChildPath`. This parameter actually accepts an array, but the `-ChildPath` parameter is still mandatory and must be specified as well:

```sh
Join-Path -Path A -ChildPath B -AdditionalChildPath C, D
```

Output is a *single* path:

```text
A\B\C\D
```

This call syntax is somewhat inconvenient if you'd like to join an arbitrary number of child paths, defined as an array. For that you may use [array splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2):

```sh
$childPaths = 'B','C','D'
Join-Path -Path A @childPaths
```

Output:

```text
A\B\C\D
```

Comment: The last one seems to work, thank you zett!

Answer (score 0):

To add to [zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42):

- **In *Windows PowerShell*, use of a *single* [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) call isn't an option for joining *more than two* path components** at a time; `-ChildPath` accepts only a *single* string, and the `[string[]]`-typed `-AdditionalChildPath`
  parameter only exists in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.

  - A simple **workaround** is to use the `-join` operator on the multiple child paths in order to combine them into a single argument (see the next section about using `-join` *instead* of `Join-Path` and associated considerations):

    ```bash
    # Windows PowerShell workaround.
    Join-Path -path 'a' -ChildPath ('b', 'c', 'd' -join '\') # -> 'a/b/c/d'
    ```
  - As an aside: By contrast, **the *`-Path`* parameter *is* `[string[]]`-typed (i.e., it accepts an *array* of string values), which means that *each* among multiple values passed to it is combined with the - one and only - `-ChildPath` value**.

    ```bash
    Join-Path -path 'a', 'b' -ChildPath 'z' # -> 'a\z', 'b\z'
    ```
- **In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you can join an *open-ended number of components***, and the **most convenient syntax is to pass all path components *as individual, positional* arguments**, because the `[string[]`-typed `-AdditionalChildPath` parameter, which accepts an array of additional components, is defined with the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` property, meaning that it collects any (remaining) *positional* arguments (i.e., those not preceded by the target parameter name, such as `-ChildPath`).

  - Together with positionally binding the `-Path` and `-ChildPath` parameters, you can simply pass *all* components positionally, **optionally in an array via [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting#splatting-with-arrays)**; e.g.:

    ```bash
    # PS v7+ only

    # Individual arguments:
    # 'a' binds positionally to -Path
    # 'b' binds positionally to -ChildPath
    # 'c' and 'd' bind to -AdditionalChildPath via ValueFromRemainingArguments
    Join-Path a b c d # -> 'a\b\c\d'

    # Ditto, via array splatting.
    # You may combine splatting with passing the first (-Path) argument
    # individually, as in zett42's answer, or also the second one (`-ChildPath`)
    $allComponents = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
    Join-Path @allComponents # -> 'a\b\c\d'
    ```

---

**Alternatives to `Join-Path`:**

**You don't strictly need `Join-Path`**, because ***string* operations may do in many cases**. However, **`Join-Path` is still worth considering** for the following reasons:

- It allows you to resolve *wildcard*-based paths to matching literal paths with the `-Resolve` switch.
- It automatically uses the platform-appropriate path separator (`\` vs. `/`)
- It prevents *duplicate* path separators, so that `Join-Path a\ b` still yields `'a\b'` on Windows, for instance.
  However, note that duplicate path separators (e.g. `a\\b`) are generally *not* a problem in that paths with them are still recognized properly.

If the path **components are available as *individual* variables or strings**, you can simply use an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) to synthesize your path:

```bash
"$PSScriptRoot\$variable\A\I\L\M\U"
```

Note: The above hard-codes the path separator as `\` - see below for cross-platform considerations.

If the path **components are available as elements of an *array*** use the **[`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) *operator*** on an array may be sufficient:

```bash
$allComponents = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
$allComponents -join '\' # -> 'a\b\c\d'

# For cross-platform use (if necessary):
$allComponents -join [IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar # -> 'a\b\c\d' or 'a/b/c/d'
```

Note:

- PowerShell itself accepts `\` and `/` *interchangeably* as path separators, so even on Unix-like platforms you can get away with using `\`, as long as it is only *PowerShell* cmdlets that interpret the resulting paths.

For the sake of completeness: You may also use the **[`[System.IO.Path]::Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.Combine)** method, which is cross-platform aware; however, there are **pitfalls**:

- You must cast a regular PowerShell array (which is `[object[]`-typed) to `[string[]]` in order for PowerShell to find the desired method overload:

  ```bash
  $allComponents = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
  # Note: [string[]] cast only required in Windows PowerShell.
  [IO.Path]::Combine([string[]] $allComponents) # -> 'a\b\c\d' or 'a/b/c/d'

  # However, you may pass *up to 4* arguments *individually*:
  [IO.Path]::Combine('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
  ```
- If a component other than the first one *starts with* a (platform-appropriate) path separator, the preceding components are *ignored*; e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Windows example
  [IO.Path]::Combine('a', 'b', '\c', 'd') # -> !! '\c\d'
  ```

Comment: As @zett42 said, -ChildPath only accepts a single string, some examples create the same subfolder in each folder, which is obviously not what I expect, the array only creates a single path, does this mean I have to repeat it?

Comment: This seems easy to do in cmd, is there a concise way in powershell? `md %a%\b\c d\e\f`

Comment: @user19418817, yes, there is - please see my update. In short: use an expandable string: `"$a\b\c d\e\f"`

Comment: I'm not a coder and never worked with loops or anything, I edited my question, do you have a better suggestion for this?

Comment: @user19418817, I'm unclear on the details of what you're trying to achieve, and I suggest you create a _new_ question post with the specific problem you're now facing, along with the expected output. The error message comes from `$dir` containing the same directory multiple times. A quick fix would be to add `-Force` to your `mkdir` command, which doesn't report an error if a target dir. already exists.